# Changing state from component to component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello i am trying to make a click function where i click a day in the calendar.
And by doing so i want to change the current day that shows in the sidebar, which happens in another component called TimeTarget.
This is where i render the calendar.

```
 <tbody>
          <tr
            v-for="(day, index) in days"
            :key="index"
            :class="[{ no_target: isHoliday(day) }, { active: moment == day.date.format('Do dddd') }]"
            class="calendar-row"
          >
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item" @click="changeDay">{{ day.date.format('D.') }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item" @click="changeDay">{{ day.date.format('dddd') }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item">{{ day.workhours }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item">{{ day.overtime }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item">{{ day.flextime }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item">{{ day.sickness }}</td>
            <td class="calendar-row__grid-item">{{ day.vacation }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

i would have thought i could do it with a function like this

```
changeDay() {
      let changeDay = this.days.day.date.format();
      TimeTarget.dayjs = changeDay;
      return dayjs;
    },
```

but i get a Cannot read property 'date' of undefined.

Comment: the best way to do this is using vuex. this what vuex stand for. but if you dont want to use vuex you can use main app data. there is another ways to do this but those two are the best

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this depends on how distant your components are. Do they share the same parent? Then they can communicate through event emitting and props:

```
parent component
    calendar > $emit('setDate', date) // emits event with the date to parent 
    sidebar  > :selected-date="date"  // receives date via prop from the parent
```

If the components share no parent or are really far from each other (the common parent is 2 or more components away) some kind of state management like Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) makes life easier.

This article explains it quite well: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/data-components-vue-js/